# How to raise same question on different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am using a Stack Exchange login ID and I am a new user.

I wanted to know if, when I write a question in the GIS community, will the same question be visible to other communities like Stack Overflow?

Can a question that has been asked in one community be linked to another one?

Or will I have to write the same question again to raise it in another community?

Answer (score 10):

Cross-posting, or asking on multiple SE sites, is generally discouraged. You should pick the most appropriate site and ask there. If little or no response, you could flag with a request that it be migrated to an alternative.

You can post a link to a question in another SE site within your question, but they don't show up in the Linked or Related sections on the right side. The question might appear in the Hot Network Questions section (the only way other communities will see it by default), but whether it gets noticed or not is another story.

If someone happens to follow both SEs, it's possible that they'll notice a question on one or the other. But for just regular/single SE users, no, they likely will not see a question posted to another SE.

This is discussed a few times on Meta SE. For example, [How to ask the same question on different sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234495/how-to-ask-the-same-question-on-different-) which is now a duplicate of the more reviewed [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: It means, copying the url link of the question and pasting to the another SE site within question box. Am i right?

Comment: @WaseemAli That could be considered correct. Typically cross-posting means putting the same full text in the question box on two sites, but just posting a link to the other site would be considered 'worse' and likely be flagged/closed/deleted pretty quickly. Now, if you post a question on one site and can't get it moved, you *could* post the full text of the same question to another site and say something like "I already asked this on whatever.se but they couldn't help and it hasn't been migrated" and include a link after.

Comment: Does this apply for cross-posting to Esri's GeoNet?

Comment: @mapBaker Not to my knowledge. Not everyone participates on the same sites, some are more active than others, and some have people with different areas of expertise following them. This has come up in comments before (I myself referred to it [here](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3672/should-statements-of-urgency-be-removed-from-questions)). Some people do frown upon it, but usually in a 'spam it everywhere and give no feedback anywhere' issue. I don't see how SE could logically make a rule 'don't ask here if you ask anywhere else on the internet'.